if文を使ってNULLを判定したい
Javaでif文を使って、入力された値がNULLかNULLではないかで判定して出力したいのですがうまくいかないのでどこが間違っているか教えていただきたいです。
*特定を避けるため一部削除しました
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args[0]==null){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else if(args[1]==null){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else if(args[2]==null){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else if(args[3]!=null){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println(  );
        }
    }
}


XY問題 なのではありませんか？ 引数の数を調べたいならそのままこちらの記事が参考になると思われます。java 101, how do I count the number of arguments passed into main? あとは明示的に空文字列が渡されたか調べるならこちらとかでしょうか？ Javaで文字列が空かnullかどうかを確認します, 【Java】どうしてString.isEmpty()ではなくStringUtils.isEmpty()を使うのか

引数の数をチェックしたいのであれば、args.length で確認できます。
if (args.length < 3){
    System.out.println("引数を3つ指定して下さい");
}


nullという文字列の可能性はないですか?
念のため、以下のように文字列検査もしてみるといいのかなぁと思いました
if("null".equals(args[0])){
            System.out.println("0");
        }

ただ、自分も @knif XY問題な気がするので、何が困っているのかHowではなくその背景を乗せてくれると、スムーズですね
